# Issue in Laravel pagination

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

I am trying to apply pagination on my laravel project. But when I put pagination code, it makes numeric pagination and when I click button for next page to show other data. Its does not work. My URL right now is
:     http://localhost/buildcrm/public/staff
and here is my URL when I click for the second page :     http://localhost/staff?page=2 .

Here is my pagination code:

```
<?php
  $users = DB::table('staff')->paginate(4);   
  $i = 0;

  foreach($users as $row) {
     $city =$row->city.','.$row->pincode; 
     $name = explode(',',$row->name);
     $i = $i + 1;
  ?>
     <tr>
         <td><?php echo $i; ?></td>
         <td><?php echo $name[0]; ?>&nbsp;<?php echo $name[1]; ?>&nbsp;<?php echo $name[2]; ?></td>
         <td>
             <a href="<?php echo 'editstaff/'.$row->staff_id; ?>" class="btn btn-xs btn-info" >Edit</a>&nbsp;<a href="<?php echo 'Deletestaff/'.$row->staff_id; ?>" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger">Delete</a>
         </td>
    </tr>

 <?php
    }
 ?>


 </tbody>
 </table>
 <div align="center"> 
     <?php echo $users->render(); ?>
 </div>
```

Comment: see when you click send page in pagination your url are not generate properly http://localhost/staff?page=2 
for that you can create a virtual host

Comment: `laravel-4` or `laravel-5`? Make up your mind and do not spam with tags irrelevant for the issue/question

Comment: Is this a laravel code block?

Comment: If this is Laravel, I don't think you're making use of the whole MVC thing properly...

Comment: sorry but I am new Laravel, just learn 2 days ago.I think when I click on next page URL like http://localhost/buildcrm/public/staff?page=2 this but right now redirect on  localhost/staff?page=2 and when I put this code Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator;
    Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginatorat controller in controller I got this error  Undefined constant 'App\Http\Controllers\Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try setting custom path like this?

$users = DB::table('staff')->paginate(4);
$users->setPath('custom/url');